# Skbio python module to support python 2

Tags: python, installation, skbio

I have python 2 installed on my machine. I want to use the skbio module for some part of my code. I tried installing skbio (pip install scikit-bio) but it says it does not support python 2 it is only available in python 3. I even tried importing skbio from future in my code but it did not work. Is there any way out I can install and use skbio module for my python 2 version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

scikit-bio dropped Python 2 support in version 0.5.0 and is now only compatible with Python 3.4+. Versions 0.4.2 and earlier are Python 2/3 compatible, so you could try out an older version:

```
pip install scikit-bio==0.4.2
```

Comment: I got this error: `cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-error=declaration-after-statement'
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Shalini\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

Comment: scikit-bio doesn't support Windows; can you try installing it on a Linux or Mac machine?

Comment: scikit-bio-0.5 supports Windows but only in Python34 or later. So now I have installed Python 3.4 on my system. But now while installing scikit-bio I ran into this = `cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-error=declaration-after-statement'
    error: command 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`